# Android app built using Xamarin does not show up on emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I have written a simple login page using xamarin forms. When I try to deploy it on emulator, the emulator opens but my app is not visible.

1) Does it take time for the app to be deployed? Or would it appear on start up?
2) Should warnings be considered? I have no errors though.

Comment: there should be a "deploying to device" window - are you sure there are no relevant messages or errors displayed?

Comment: Yes i am sure about it. After waiting for few minutes, app turned up in my emulator. I am trying on a different device and now its not showing in the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Most Android emulated devices are slow. I have found that some of them simply won't render an app. This is not an indication that the physical device, which you are trying to emulate, won't work however. Try testing what works in an emulator and then creating a copy of what works in the device manager. Then make slight changes that are closer to the target device in the copy. Deploy every time to ensure that it is working. This process takes patience.  If you are fortunate enough to have the physical device, debug through the USB connection.